# [Android]I have to move an image from one position to another with arc path animation

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, viewanimator

I have view at (x1,y1) I have to move it to (x2,y2) where the view follows an inverted U path, it should look like the view is jumping and following arc and moves to its final position.

I'm new to canvas, path and animations, so any suggestions would help

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MotionLayout](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/animations/motionlayout).

Helps you manage motion and widget animation in your app.

Comment: In MotionLayout 
KeyPosition can help you achieve complex motion 
 https://youtu.be/3HQMCyAkWTE